# zsh: completion rules for ssh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

in `zsh`, I can autocomplete hostnames from `/etc/hosts`, ie:

```
ssh f<TAB>
```

will offer completions for hosts starting with `f`.

This is configured in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_hosts`:

```
local ipstrip='[:blank:]#[^[:blank:]]#'

zstyle -t ":completion:${curcontext}:hosts" use-ip && useip=yes
[[ -n $useip ]] && ipstrip=
if (( ${+commands[getent]} )); then
  _cache_hosts=(${(s: :)${(ps:\t:)${(f)~~"$(_call_program hosts getent hosts 2>/dev/null)"}##${~ipstrip}}})
else
  _cache_hosts=(${(s: :)${(ps:\t:)${${(f)~~"$(</etc/hosts)"}%%\#*}##${~ipstrip}}})
fi

....

_hosts=( "$_cache_hosts[@]" )
```

however, it only works if `/etc/hosts` file has the format 'IP'  'hostname', ie:

```
192.168.1.4      foo.mydomain.com
```

it will not work if IP is missing:

```
                 foo.mydomain.com
```

How can I modify the completion script, so that hostnames without IP  are also completed?

Completion of hostnames without IP from `/etc/hosts` works fine in `bash_completion`. So I am just trying to get the same behavior on `zsh`.

Comment: What makes you think that `/etc/hosts` and the output of `getent hosts` actually work like that?

Comment: I put all the hostnames I want to complete into `~/.hosts` and then set `zstyle -e ':completion:*' hosts 'reply=($(< ~/.hosts))'`

Comment: The express purpose of `/etc/hosts` is to associate IP addresses with hostnames. Each line (unless empty or a comment) *must* have one IP address followed by at least one hostname (the first one should be the canonical hostname, the others are aliases). Lines without IP addresses are not valid.

Comment: If you disable `HashKnownHosts` in your ssh configuration (`~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`), than `zsh` can also use the entries in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` for completion (You may have to remove the the current entries in order to repopulate it with plain text host names).

Comment: https://www.codyhiar.com/blog/zsh-autocomplete-with-ssh-config-file/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend doing this, which would use your (and the system's) ssh known hosts file instead:

```
zstyle -e ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|sftp|rsh|rsync):hosts' hosts 'reply=(${=${${(f)"$(cat {/etc/ssh_,~/.ssh/known_}hosts(|2)(N) /dev/null)"}%%[# ]*}//,/ })'
```

If you're still wanting to use /etc/hosts instead:

```
strip='[:blank:]#[^[:blank:]]#'
zstyle -e ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|sftp|rsh|rsync):hosts' hosts 'reply=(${(s: :)${(ps:\t:)${${(f)~~"$(</etc/hosts)"}%%\#*}##${~strip}}})'
```

Best of luck!

Comment: No thanks, I don't want to use `known hosts file`. And regarding the second solution, how can I achieve that by modifying '/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_hosts` ? I don't want to put this into my `.zshrc`.

Comment: You can replace the line `_cache_hosts=(${(s: :)${(ps:\t:)${(f)~~"$(_call_program hosts getent hosts 2>/dev/null)"}##${~ipstrip}}})` in `_hosts` with `_cache_hosts=(${(s: :)${(ps:\t:)${${(f)~~"$(</etc/hosts)"}%%\#*}##${~ipstrip}}})` I believe to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Add a filter function to `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_hosts`:

```
provide_missing_ip() {
   while read x ; do 
      set -- $x
      if [ ! "$1" ] || [ "${1%%[^#]*}" ] || [ "$2" ] ; then
          echo "$x"
      else
          ip=`dig +short $2`
          [ "$ip" ] || ip="240.0.0.0"
          printf "%s\t%s\n" $1 $2
      fi
   done
}
```

How it works:

1. If there's two entries, or a blank, or a comment, just output those.
2. If there's just a hostname, try to provide an *IP* address with `dig`.
3. Failing that, (which *shouldn't* happen, but let's say it's an intentionally bogus hostname for testing purposes), use a harmless dummy *IP* address of "*240.0.0.0*", (see [*Bandrami's* answer to
   "*IP address that is the equivalent of /dev/null*"](https://superuser.com/a/698251/582419)).

Use the new function to parse the output of `getent` or `< /etc/hosts` in the troublesome completion code:

```
if (( ${+commands[getent]} )); then
  _cache_hosts=(${(s: :)${(ps:\t:)${(f)~~"$(_call_program hosts getent hosts 2>/dev/null | provide_missing_ip )"}##${~ipstrip}}})
else
  _cache_hosts=(${(s: :)${(ps:\t:)${${(f)~~"$(provide_missing_ip </etc/hosts)"}%%\#*}##${~ipstrip}}})
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The `hosts` file must be in the format `IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]`, so your approach should be to fix your hosts file, not to get one program snippet working around your broken file. Other programs may run in problems too, if your `hosts` is broken, so this would be the only sane solution to your use case.
If it's a dynamical IP you are targeting, and you do not want to use any of the better workarounds provided above, consider writing a script which dynamically changes your `hosts` according to this changing address.